# If I deleted a question of mine, does other user's rep go away?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Say I have a question and somebody answers. He gets upvotes and I even make him the best answer. But later I delete my question. Does his rep go away because I deleted my own question? Or only the rep I gave him. Like when I gave him an upvote and best answer. And the other people who upvoted for him stays?

Comment: If the user's answer is upvoted, you yourself can't delete it. But yes, if a post is deleted, the rep is lost from that post.

Comment: @Kendra A downvote from someone else would allow the OP to delete it, as it would cease to have a positive score.

Comment: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Someone else would need to downvote the answer for you to be *able* to delete it (questions that have an answer with a positive score cannot be deleted by their author), but if someone else did cast such a downvote, then yes, the answerer would lose the 8 rep they had gained from the answer.